# Dynamic DLL loading reference issue

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-assembly, restsharp

I am facing with a problem when loading dynamically a library with a shared reference. I understood where the problem could be, but I don't really know how I can fix it.

I will try to explain my problem better, this is my structure:

I have 3 assemblies

- DataProviderAssembly
- ContractsAppAssembly
- AppAssembly

I start saying that I can not currently use MEF.

The "DataProviderAssembly" loads dinamically the "AppAssembly" because it has a type that implements the IApp interface from the "ContractsAssembly".
Following the code below, when I try to call the method OnSignRequest from the App class, I get a MissingMethodException. Seems that the method were not found, but, if I remove the "RestRequest" parameter, everything works fine.
I think that, the dynamic loading of that DLL miss some reference information for the dependent assemblies.

```
**ContractsAppAssembly**
public interface IApp {
    void GetData();
}

public abstract class MainClassBase : IApp {
   public virtual void GetData(){
        //Do Stuff
   }
    protected void OnSignRequest(RestRequest request){
        //calling sign request event
    }
}

public abstract class SecondClassBase : MainClassBase {
    // i need this because it overrides other methods i didn't specify here
}

**AppAssembly**
public class App : SecondClassBase {
    public override void GetData(){

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        base.OnSignRequest(request);//<-- this throws a MissingMethodException
    }
}

**DataProviderAssembly**
public class DataProvider{
    public DataProvider{
        string[] appsLibs = Directory.GetFiles(appsFolderPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (string appLib in appsLibs)
        {
            Assembly appAssemlby = Assembly.LoadFrom(appLib);
            Type appType = providerAssemlby.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IApp).Name, true) != null && !t.IsAbstract);
            if (appType == default(Type))
            {
                continue;
            }
            try
            {
                IApp app = (IApp )Activator.CreateInstance(appType);
                initApp(app);
                this.apps.Add(app.Name, app);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the assemblies reference RestSharp.dll, the build structure is the following:

```
Debug:
DataProviderAssembly.dll
Debug/Apps:
ContractsAppAssembly.dll
AppAssembly.dll
```

Obviously the DataProviderAssembly.dll has the "probing" option inside of the app.config file.

Debugging this code I cannot reach the "base.OnSignRequest" line of code inside of the App class , but, if I declare virtual the method "OnSignRequest" inside of the MainClassBase, the debugger let me reach that line of code giving me the exception only when I try to do a step on.

Comment: I have just discovered that the problem is caused by the build folder structure. If I build everything in the same folder I don't get the error. But it's weird on my opionion,
DataProvider reference only the ContractsAssembly.
The AppAssembly reference only the ContractsAssembly.
DataProvider and AppAssembly are in 2 different folders. May be that they are trying to use two different RestSharp.dll?